# How do you find the Jordan matrix with a respect to a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question as follows:

Let A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\\ 1 & 3 & 0 \\\ -2 & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}

a) Verify that $(0,0,1)^T$ is an eigenvector of A

b) Verify also that **u** = $(-1,1,1)^T $is an eigenvector of $A$ and that if **v** = $(0,1,0)^T$, then $A$**v** = 2**v** + **u**.

c) Hence find an invertible matrix $P$ and a Jordan matrix $J$ such that $P^{-1} A P = J.$

I am able to solve parts (a) & (b) but I got stuck at finding the Jordan matrix J for part (c).

The solution makes use of the earlier eigenvectors and the "representation of A with respect to this basis" but I am unsure of the latter statement.

Could someone help me out with part (c)?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The representation of the matrix $A$ with respect to the basis 
$\{(0,0,1),(-1,1,1),(0,1,0)\}$ will be
$$
\pmatrix{
-1&0&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2
}
$$

Comment: Well, Write A in basis $\{(0,0,1),(-1,1,1),(0,1,0)\}$, see answer Omnomnomnom. The matrix P sought is $\{(0,0,1),(-1,1,1),(0,1,0)\}$ in form column.

Comment: Yes I understand the diagonal consists of the eigenvalues which is \lambda = -1 and \lambda = 2 with a multiplicity of 2. But how does one determine the superdiagonal and its entries?

Comment: @Julian note that $Av = 2v + u$.  So, the third column should be
$$
2 \cdot (0,0,1)^T + 1 \cdot (0,1,0)^T
$$
hence the superdiagonal $1$.  On the other hand, $Au = 2u$, so the second column should be
$$
2 \cdot (0,1,0)^T
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry but shouldn't 2v + u be: 2 \cdot (0,1,0)^T + 1 \cdot (-1,1,1)^T? That will give (-1,3,1)^T?

Comment: Yes, that is the representation of the $2v + u$ with respect to the *canonical basis* (in other words, that is the "actual vector").  However, what we want is the representation of $2v + u$ *with respect to the basis* $\{(0,0,1),u,v\}$, since we are finding the representation of $A$ with respect to this basis.

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately I am still unable to find the representation of A with respect to the basis. I can derive P but think I am lacking in some knowledge on the basis part.

Comment: There are 3 vectors in our basis: $v_1,v_2,v_3$.  We have $Av_1 = -v_1$, $Av_2 = 2v_2$, and $Av_3 = v_2 + 2v_3$.  With this information alone, we can deduce the matrix of $A$ with respect to this basis.